# Update Jobs CV to allow type of student to be indicated

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, education

One thing that has been bothering me for awhile is that Careers doesn't provide a means of saying what type of student you currently are. While this could be a fairly long list, it would be nice to distinguish if you are a graduate student or not, and if you are a part-time student or not.

This change could allow companies to have a more nuanced search and allow developers have a more nuanced banner.

Right now student status is being put forward first, i.e.

> **Experienced Developer**
>   Currently a **student**, **Senior Software Engineer**

However, practical purposes professional experience should be put first, i.e.

> **Experienced Developer**
>   Senior Software Engineer at Some Company, currently a graduate student (evening)